# String interpolation not working in closure

Tags: groovy

I am looking at GString $ keyword and want to print the range.

```
('A'..'Z').each {item ->
    print '$item'
}
```

I was expecting the range A..Z to be printed, but its printing $item$item....
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quoted strings are `java.lang.String` and interpolation doesn't work here. You need to change it to `GString`, use double quotes:

```
('A'..'Z').each {item ->
    print "$item"
}
```

It's explained pretty well in [Groovy's documentation about strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings).